# geolocation pass value to url.action on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone please help with this problem, I'm trying to get the latitude longitude values using geolocation when the page loads, problem is, I'm having problems trying to figure out how to pass the values to the mvc partial view, I have properbly been looking to long at it now, so hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can see my problem.

Thanks

George

```
<script>
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("Geo-Enabled");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        @*var actionUrl = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather", new {latitude = lat,longitude = lon}))';*@
        alert(lat + ' ' + lon);
            @*url: '@Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather", new {latitude = '+ position.coords.latitude +',longitude = ' + position.coords.longitude+'})',*@
        url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather", new {latitude = lat,longitude = lon}))'; @*<<<<<<Does not work*@
    }
function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert( "Unable to display accurate weather forcast, location denied.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert( "Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        alert( "The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        alert( "An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Sorry gone away and come back and sorted it, just needed a break :-)

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather"))',
            type: 'get',
            alert: (lat),
            data: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lon
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't execute when generating the action URL.

You can try this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather")';
url = url + "?latitude=" + position.coords.latitude + '&longitude=' + position.coords.longitude;
```

or

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CurrentConditions","Weather", new {latitude = -1,longitude = -2})';
url = url .replace("-1", position.coords.latitude);
url = url .replace("-2", position.coords.longitude);
```

Comment: @George Phillipson, thats great :), if possible try out my solution. You can always pass data as ajax payload. And please tag your question properly for better visiblity.

Comment: Hi Satpal thanks will do, its amazing what a bar of chocolate can do :-)